# aidl.exe E. Error while creating directories: Invalid argument

Tags: java

I have created a game with BuilBox and when I come to import into eclipse.
it give me this error

```
[2016-05-08 15:19:52 - com.companyname.gamename] aidl.exe E  5892  9448 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
```

anyone have a solution

Comment: Please add the code and error as **text** to your question. It should be minimalistic and reproducable. [As explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: can you please share the error code here ?